# How to connect to Exchange online API from PHP

Tags: php, exchangewebservices

I have a task at hand which requires me to connect Exchange Online account and list all the calendar entries in PHP.

I have read through many Microsoft help doc but it all refers to c# code. Can someone please guide me through steps to achieve this using PHP.

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
$ews = new ExchangeWebServices($host, $username, $password);

$request = new EWSType_FindItemType();
$request->Traversal = EWSType_ItemQueryTraversalType::SHALLOW;

$request->ItemShape = new EWSType_ItemResponseShapeType();
$request->ItemShape->BaseShape =
        EWSType_DefaultShapeNamesType::DEFAULT_PROPERTIES;

$request->CalendarView = new EWSType_CalendarViewType();
$request->CalendarView->StartDate = date('c', strtotime('01/01/2011 -00'));
$request->CalendarView->EndDate = date('c', strtotime('01/31/2011 -00'));

$request->ParentFolderIds = new EWSType_NonEmptyArrayOfBaseFolderIdsType();
$request->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId =
        new EWSType_DistinguishedFolderIdType();
$request->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId->Id =
        EWSType_DistinguishedFolderIdNameType::CALENDAR;
```

With this: https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews

Comment: We created an account in Office 360 and trying to access the calendar there. Exchange Online Service NOT Exchange 2007 or others.

We are trying to connect exchange online account https://portal.microsoftonline.com/.  Will we be able to connect online or this code works with local exchange mail server

What should be the host name ? We are trying to use vinniehash.onmicrosoft.com
Thats was generated when we created the account

Comment: Why don't you run the supplied code against your server to find out?

Comment: @fnkr did you test it, what did you come up with, did the php-ews library work against your vinniehash.onmicrosoft.com server hosted at microsoftonline?